# Why is there such a difference in thr amount RAM used?

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, ram, 4.2-jelly-bean, processes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The RAM total of the apps “Running” never equals the “Used Ram” shown below on the scale](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/the-ram-total-of-the-apps-running-never-equals-the-used-ram-shown-below-on-t)

I'm owning a Nexus 7 running on 4.2.1. This is a screenshot of the amount of RAM in use. The sum of processes using the RAM is clearly less than the amount of RAM *that is shown is being used.* why?[image]

**This is the complete list of running processes.**

This is the list of **cached processes.** Also note, under developer options the **maximum number of apps running is background is limited to 4**

[image]

Comment: Try shutting down chrome completely, hold down the home button until a list of tasks appear, than swipe to the left to let android safely and gracefully shut those background chrome processes away....

Comment: And see [The RAM total of the apps “Running” never equals the “Used Ram” shown below on the scale](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/16575/) for an answer to your question.

Comment: @t0mm13b - No, that did not make any difference. Chrome isn't hogging 300+MB, anyhow.